# random change class on existing list of element

Tags: jquery, random

the process should be:
I control how many elements are present;
I create a unique random array of those numbers;
I use the random sequence to give a class to the corresponding element every 5 seconds.
But it does not work. what did i do wrong?

html

```
<div class="wrapper-sx">
    <h4>...</h4>
    <h4>...</h4>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var items = $("#working .wrapper-sx").find("h4");
var number = items.length;
var arr = [];
while(arr.length < number){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * number) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
};
console.log(arr);
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    setInterval(function () {
        items.removeClass("active");
        items.eq(arr[i]).addClass("active");
        console.log(i);
    }, 5000);
};
```

thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

That is because your parent-div selector is wrong. You don't have any element with id `#working`.
Also, If you would like some kind of animation, I would suggest placing `setInterval()` outside the loop.

```js
var items = $(".wrapper-sx").find("h4");
var number = items.length;
//console.log(number);

setInterval(function () {
let r =  Math.floor(Math.random() * number); //note that now for each iteration I am forming a new randowm number
console.log(r+1);
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        $(items[i]).removeClass("active");
        if(i === r){
          $(items[i]).addClass("active");
        }
        //console.log(i);
   
}
 }, 5000);
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-sx">
    <h4>1</h4>
    <h4>2</h4>
    <h4>3</h4>
    <h4>4</h4>
    <h4>5</h4>
    <h4>6</h4>
    <h4>7</h4>
    <h4>8</h4>
    <h4>9</h4>
    <h4>10</h4>
</div>
```

I added some css for visual representation

Comment: i don't understand something. why doble '$(items[i]).removeClass("active");' ? anyway, something wrong again, class 'active' be stopped on only one h4. I want add class to one different h4 every 5 seconds. your way apply the class to the same h4 everytime.

Comment: the double `$(items[i]).removeClass("active");` is a typo. So you want one h4 have that `active` class at a time?

Comment: Edited, If something is still missing  please do tell

Comment: yes, I want every 5 seconds one h4 have `active` class.

Comment: Try the snippet, see if this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved the question:

```
    var items = $(".wrapper-sx").find("h4");
    var item_number = items.length;
    var arr = [];
    while(arr.length < item_number){
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * item_number);
        if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
    };
    var indexElement = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if(indexElement<item_number){
            items.removeClass("active");
            items.eq(arr[indexElement]).addClass("active");
            indexElement++;
        } else{
            indexElement = 0;
        }
     }, 5000);
```

thanks for all ;)